# JSF Проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: java, кодировка, intellij-idea, jsf

Разбираюсь с JSF, работа с локалями.

Создал 3 properties-файла: messages.properties, messages_en_US.properties, messages_ru_RU.properties.

Кодировка UTF-8.

Указал в faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>nsl.messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>ru</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>ru</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

На странице в браузере отображается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменение кодировки через настройки браузера не дает никакого результата, текст вообще не изменяется. Пробовал в IDE экспериментировать с различными кодировками properties - результата тоже нет.

Использую Intellij idea, запускал на glassfish 4, tomcat, jetty.

Может у кого-нибудь была такая же история? Какую настройку я не учёл?

Answer (score 2):

Если кодишь в Intellij Idea, то смени кодировку листинга.

Answer (score 1):

Причина оказалась в Intellij Idea 14.1.3. Всё прекрасно работает в Eclipse и Idea 13-ой версии.

Answer (score 0):

1. Надо посмотреть какую кодировку использует сама страница.
2. А что в properties-файле написано ? Хорошо бы сделать отладочную печать чтобы узнать, что именно читается из ресурса.

Comment: 1. В index.xhtml прописано <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. В браузере стоит UTF-8.  <br/>  2. В properties: `title=Электронная библиотека
welcome_title=Добро пожаловать в электронную библиотеку
enter_name=Введите ваше имя
name=Имя:`

Comment: Именно так прописано ? Или это все-таки преобразовано в коды в юникоде ?

Comment: Изначально в .properties прописывается: \u0418\u043C\u044F и т.д. В Idea есть настройка transparent native-to-ascii conversion, я её включил, всё поэтому по-русски отображается.

Answer (score 0):

Более подробно о Transparent native-to-ascii conversion можно прочесть [здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-encoding-for-properties-files.html)